# How can I build PHP Extension from PHP Code

Tags: php, php-extension

I am looking to convert my PHP library code as a PHP extension. The full library is under a namespace. There are many PHP classes I am using under my library.

Is there any tool which convert the PHP code to .so and .dll PHP extension (with the namespace usage) ?

Writing the code in C or CPP is too much of work.

Comment: Well as far as I know the C route is the only way.

Comment: There is no tool that will automagically convert PHP code to a PHP Extension, but tools like [Zephir](https://github.com/phalcon/zephir/) provide a half-way DSL that can easily be converted from straight PHP and then compiled against Zephir to build a PHP extension.... I'm actually showing how to do exactly that in a tutorial at the PHPNW conference next month

Comment: Can I use the namespace also with Zephir ?

Comment: Yes you use namespacing with Zephir, take a look at the [docs](http://zephir-lang.com/) to see what it does

Comment: Thanks. Post your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no tool that will automagically convert PHP code to a PHP Extension, but tools like [Zephir](https://github.com/phalcon/zephir/) provide a half-way DSL that can easily be converted from straight PHP and then compiled against Zephir to build a PHP extension... and yes, it does work with namespaces

The [Zephir docs](http://zephir-lang.com/) are pretty good, and give a decent explanation of how to write code for the Zephir DSL, and there are [blog posts like marmelab's](http://marmelab.com/blog/2013/12/05/converting-the-symfony-stopwatch-component-from-php-to-zephir.html) that show how to convert a PHP (namespaced) class to an extension using Zephir.

**Edit**

Since posting this answer, I've also discovered [PHP-to-Zephir](https://github.com/fezfez/php-to-zephir) which claims to be able to convert PHP code to the Zephir DSL, although I haven't tested it in any way

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Zephir is the tool which I am looking for and I successfully managed to convert my classes to the PHP extension with the help of this tool.

Comment: I managed to change my PHP code to extension with both  PHP-to-Zephir and Zephir.